# Como colocar somente Mês e Ano no DataPicker (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, aplicação-desktop

Por default (pelo javaFX scene bilder) vem o datapicker mês, dia e ano. Gostaria de saber como tirar o dia, e deixar somente mês e ano. Se tiver como, valeu!

Comment: Olá Leonardo, desculpe ressuscitar a pergunta, mas não ficou claro para mim exatamente o que você está querendo. A ideia é não exibir os dias no componente ou apenas descartar o dia na hora de obter a data escolhida pelo usuário?

Answer (score 3):

Dê uma olhada nesse [artigo](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-date-picker/). A parte que configura o formato que você deseja é:

```
birthdayDatePicker.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));`
```